# All customers in one db or separate dbs?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I've built a school management system for my own needs. The size of tables ranges from ~200 rows to ~30,000 rows /at the end of school year/.

Some of my friends have seen the system and they urge me to make it available to other schools. I'd like to give it a try at least with a few schools for now. Considering my current architecture and  shared hosting I'd have to store all schools in **single db** and so 2 questions bother me:

1. Can MySql easily handle tables with >300,000 rows?
2. The system is based on Yii2 at the moment, I've optimized it for max performance - do you think it's wise to try or better work towards solution with a dedicated server and separate db for each school?

I don't know if it's wise to store all students, attendance, payments etc info from my and 10 others schools across shared tables in single db. I'd better ask than cause trouble to myself..

Any advice is more than welcome:)

Comment: "Can MySql easily handle tables with >300,000 rows? " MySQL can handle millions of records with ease when indexed correctly

Comment: 300,000 rows is a trivial amount when it comes to database management. It would probably be better to have a separate schema for each school. I'm not sure why you would want to mix multiple schools together.

Comment: Well this question is primarily opinion-based some will advice make one db for all schools and some will advice to create 1 db per school.. Both methods have there own advantages and disadvantages... For example one db for all would require some kind of views to filter the records which the school is allowed to see with a 1 db per school you dont have that "problem"

Comment: The most important thing I can think of is that if the data is all held together, there can be issues of data protection.  Separate databases at least gives you a basic form of data separation allowing you to restrict the users from one school access to others data by database permissions rather than application logic.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with one table, MySQL can handle millions of rows.  My only advice would be: As you have multiple "clear" sections, i.e. attendance, payments, etc, and you are expanding to multiple schools, I would probably separate the into tables for each section.  This will allow for greater expansion in the future.  You can expand each individually with more columns in each as required without creating a behemoth of a table if and when your system gets really big.  I think I'm trying to say future proof now to save a potential headache later.

Comment: @emsimpson92 At the very moment I'm running the site on shared hosting (with decent params though) where I need to sign into admin section to create db. The created db I hardcode then into Yii2 config file that runs the whole system. So currently there are technical limitations at stake. The system is not able to create dbs in current env.

Comment: @NigelRen For now I've implemented authorization for teachers, parents and students - it works fine - everybody has access only to specific data and so I think I could scale the logic.

Comment: So create a table for students (from all schools) and a table for each school. In your students table you can include the school ID for each student.

Comment: @Stephen don't get me wrong:) I'm not packing all data into one tb; Have all logical pieces in respective tables with multiple junction tables at times; only some tbs are >300k rows long and thus the doubts.

Comment: @emsimpson92 yep, that was exactly my idea but was concerned about the size and performance of some tbs. Attendance tb eg has status for every single student for every class they can be present/absent/late for. After the current school year it's 30k rows for my students only. I think I'll have to check how many schools are interested in my app. For now I know I can easily go with a few tens even without worrying about MySql limits. Thank you guys!

Comment: *it works fine* isn't something I would want to be held to when schools start getting other schools data showing up.

Comment: @NigelRen I've tested the system against manipulating GET/POST params, local storage data, SQL injection etc. When the teacher requests the data of students they teach, JOIN query is run to fetch only those students from the group where teacher_id matches the authenticated teacher - one of the ways alongside filters I run in controllers. It works fine - however colloquial it sounded:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of
>   it) in programming

You should not worry about this at the moment. Start running your application and as you scale, identify the bottlenecks and then try to figure out a solution for it.

> Can MySql easily handle tables with >300,000 rows?

First things first, use the best normlization principles to structure your tables and relations. MySQL is pretty good at handling rows up to 10,000,000. but it also depends on how you are indexing/querying the data. Use proper db indexes on the columns you frequenty use for lookup. A big no to "like" queries but if you must, then use a search engine like (elastic, solr).

> The system is based on Yii2 at the moment, I've optimized it for max
>   performance - do you think it's wise to try or better work towards
>   solution with a dedicated server and separate db for each school?

I have a very little idea about Yii2, but certainly there are much better frameworks available in php which you can give a try eg. larvel ([this will give you a better idea](https://opensource.com/business/16/6/which-php-framework-right-you)). Ofcourse, best would be to host this application on a dedicated server. why to waste money when you can have private VPS just in 5$ from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/).

> I don't know if it's wise to store all students, attendance, payments
>   etc info from my and 10 others schools across shared tables in single
>   db. I'd better ask than cause trouble to myself..

There is absolutely no problem storing students, attendance, payments info in the same database, just structure your tables properly.

Comment: Good point on premature optimization - thx:) As to Laravel, I've had an episode with v3 but after moving my codebase to v4 my app was like a 10kg snail.. sluggish and unresponsive. It was probably cache issue on my shared hosting. Anyway, Yii rocks and rolls when it comes to performance:)

Comment: Laravel may beat Yii in some aspects, but performance is definitely not one of them, so proposing it as a replacement when performance is a concern does not make much sense. :)